# How to define a helper method available across application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, methods

In multiple models, I need to check if two sets of dates overlap or not, so I wrote the following method:

```
def do_dates_overlap(second_record)
  test = ((self.pickupdate - second_record.returndate) * (second_record.pickupdate - self.returndate)).to_i
  if test > 0
    return "yes"
  elsif test == 0
    return "edge"
  elsif test < 0
    return "no"
  end
end
```

But I'm not sure where to put this so that it's available across multiple models. Incidentally, right now I need it in the Request model, but when I put it in Request model as such:

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base

    def do_dates_overlap(second_record)
    ....
    end

end
```

And then in the console as a test I ran `Request.last.do_dates_overlap(Request.first)`, I got the error: `NoMethodError: undefined method`do_dates_overlap' for #`, so not sure what's going on...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Module for this behavior.

In app/models/concerns/ create a new module (i.e. datecheck.rb)

```
module Datecheck
  def do_dates_overlap(second_record)
    test = ((self.pickupdate - second_record.returndate) * (second_record.pickupdate - self.returndate)).to_i
    if test > 0
      return "yes"
    elsif test == 0
      return "edge"
    elsif test < 0
      return "no"
    end
  end
end
```

In your class:

```
class Request
  include Datecheck
end
```

The class will now have access to the methods defined in the module. Include the module in any class that needs the shared method/s.

Modules are a nice way to separate shared methods by their area of concern (in this case, working with dates).

Comment: This worked great, thanks! If you don't mind, I'd love to learn... why was it that when I put this method in `class Request` itself and executed it on an instance of Request, I was still getting the error I was getting? That was befuddling to me.

Comment: @james because you defined that method as an `instance method`, thus you should've used it as `Request.new.do_dates_overlap`. If you want to define it as a `class method`, you need to define it as `def self.do_dates_overlap`.

Comment: you probably forgot to `reload!` your console. Your code was right